# webpackJsonp changes the chunkHash

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, chunks

```js
vendors: {
 minSize: 20000,
 test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
 chunks: 'initial',
 name(module) {
    // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
    // or node_modules/packageName
    const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
    // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
    return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
 },
 reuseExistingChunk: true
}
```

In the above cacheGroup I am trying to split each node_module, with the output file name of `c[chunkhash].js`

I expect 2 different pages having a common import, such as `axios` should have the same 'chunkHash', but to my surprise that is not the case.

After reviewing the chunks, i figured out that the 2 chunks have the same body, just their webpackJsonp different.

chunk1

```js
(window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || []).push([[1], {
    4: function (e, t, r) {
        "use strict";
        (function (e) {
            r.d(t, "a", (function () {
                return ye
            }));
            var n, o, i, a, c = r(0), u = r.n(c), s = r(5), l = r.n(s), f = r(6), p = r.n(f), d = r(1), h = r.n(d),
                y = r(7), T = r.n(y), b = "bodyAttributes", m = "htmlAttributes", g = "titleAttributes", v = {
                    BASE: "base",
                    BODY: "body",
                    HEAD: "head",
                    HTML: "html",
...
```

chunk 2

```js
(window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || []).push([[2], {
    5: function (e, t, r) {
        "use strict";
        (function (e) {
            r.d(t, "a", (function () {
                return ye
            }));
            var n, o, i, a, c = r(0), u = r.n(c), s = r(6), l = r.n(s), f = r(7), p = r.n(f), d = r(1), h = r.n(d),
                y = r(8), T = r.n(y), b = "bodyAttributes", m = "htmlAttributes", g = "titleAttributes", v = {
                    BASE: "base",
                    BODY: "body",
                    HEAD: "head",
                    HTML: "html",
...
```

Both the chunks have the same body, but different Jsonp indexes. in chunk1 its `4` and in chunk2 its `5`

This causes the browser to download the same thing twice.

Is there a walk around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, that this is the main difference between a **multi-compiler** and **multi-entry** webpack configuration.

When you do a multi-compiler config for webpack, then you lose the ability to reuse chunks and do better code splitting.

Hence, try sticking to multi-entry webpack configs and single runtime